# My outliner window is gone after accidentally deleted it, how do i get it back?

Tags: outliner

My Outliner window is gone after i deleted it by accident, and i have no clue how to get it back!! please please help, i need it back and i have looked everywhere. Thanks[image: The red rectangle is where the Outliner Window is supposed to be]

Answer (score 1):

Place your cursor exactly to this spot and your cursor will change into white cross, when this happen, press and pull down...

[image]

New window will open again but it will be different window so click the button and select your outliner:

[image]

And you are back to normal... And just for your information, this is how you closed it. If you create that cross on existing window and pull opposite direction (up) it will do this :
[image]

and it will merge over that window with the outliner

Comment: ok thank you so so much! fixed everything :)