# How do i close the windows i opened using horizontal in 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

i am not able to close these tabs.
Using version 2.8.
Can anyone help?

Comment: left click on one of the corners of the windows and drag it up or down to collapse the other window?

Comment: Or hover the mouse over the join between the windows until the cursor changes to a double-headed arrow, right click, and choose 'Join areas'. then move the mouse into the window that you want to close. Read the [Blender Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html).

Comment: Here you have shown how opening and closing works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234554/128477

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165915/110840

Answer (score 2):

I always thought I mainly collapsed and split windows more or less by coincidence but it is quite easy:

1. If you want to split a window as you already did, go into the top left corner of the window until the cursor becomes a cross. Then left-click and drag.
   [image]
2. If you want to collapse a window, you go to the bottom-left corner of the window above until the cursor becomes a cross, then left-click and drag. You can then decide by changing the dragging direction if you want to close the upper or lower window.
   [image]
3. The same applies to other corners if you want to split or collapse vertically. Only one thing there is to notice: if you have for example one large horizontal window and above or below there are more windows split vertically, then you can't collapse them vertically because the windows have to be the same size. Same applies for the other direction, you can't collapse horizontally if the windows differ in vertical size.
   [image]

Comment: it looks like it will soon be possible to collapse a window even though it is a bigger one

Comment: Oh, is it? Interesting... might be ehlpful sometimes. But as long as the OP is using 2.8 these changes will not be applicable I guess.

Comment: that's what Pablo Vazquez said in a video but I don't know when it is supposed to be released

Comment: Actually I've just downloaded Blender 3 and it's not exactly what I said, it's even the opposite, you can drag a small window and it will extend and cut a big one: https://zupimages.net/up/21/41/page.gif